# Any tool can simulate mobilephone browser?

Tags: jsp, mobile

I need to convert current `jsp` pages to a website to a format that suitable to view in mobilephone browser.
I am developing the web application in winxp pro on a PC, but the problem is I do not have a mobilephone browser to know how the webpage appears in the mobilephone.

May I know does there exist any handphone browser simulator software thus I can view how the webpage appear in the handphone directly from PC?

Answer (score 0):

I always use a chrome extension for the exact purpose you are mentioning about. This one
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/window-resizer/kkelicaakdanhinjdeammmilcgefonfh?hl=en

This is good for quick testing.

However it just resizes your browser and does not give the actual feel of a mobile browser. One thing that is evident is the difference in the dropdown lists in real device and the web browser.

For example a drop down on a regular browser
[image]

and the same one on iOS device looks like this

[image]

Hope it is clear to list the difference. There are many such subtle differences which you would come to know only by using the device/emulator.
You can use the emulators if you want to test it how it looks on the real device.
If installing one is not possible, then http://iphone4simulator.com/ is what I found.

http://android-emulator.org/ could be useful as well.

All depends on what features you want to use from the phone. If you are using features like camera, then these emulators wont be much helpful to you, however if you just want to test how your web page looks on the mobile device, then the emulators do a pretty good job.

Answer (score 0):

Try

http://www.studiopress.com/responsive/

I like this one for testing response designs, perhaps it helps you?

Answer (score 0):

A quick and easy option, on Firefox/Chrome you could add the Web-Developer addon available here:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/web-developer/

It contains a "resize" option allowing you to edit the resolution and view responsive layouts, see here:  As anoop stated this is just a browser resize too.